# Future Task on Web - returns the old result in the new execution

Tags: web-services, jax-rs, threadpool, futuretask

I created a WebService that runs a algorithm that takes 15 minutes running. The algorithm returns a result (JSON).

Because of the result, I am using a thread "Future Task". After I deploy the application, when I run, it returns me the correct value.

Then I run the algorithm again without restarting the Glassfish and the result is the old. How can I solve this?

Code:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("getValues")
    public String getValuesAlgorithm() throws Exception {        


        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();        
        Future <String> future = executor.submit(new Task());

        String result = future.get();

        executor.shutdown();

        return result;
    }

    class Task implements Callable<String> {


        //algorithm is executed here...

        return result;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why use executor when you are still going to wait for result and block the client request? Can you also post code for `Task` class.

Comment: Is there another way to use future call without executor? I'm using this because I want to execute the task and get a result. Btw, the code just run a n algorithm that return a JSON. Nothing more. Thanks, guy. Yes, this algorithm must be executed when the previous finishes.